# Karate: Question mark gets encoded as part of path

Tags: karate

I am testing a search API. I need to send different query params depending on the test case name. Code like below works, but it sends both params for all test cases.

```
Given path '/search'
And param merchantId = 'abc'
And param email = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

I want one param to be sent with one test case and another param with another test case. So I tried like below, but the question mark after "search" gets encrypted and sent to the server.

```
* if('<testcaseName>' == 'search by merchantId') karate.set('pathVar','/search?merchantId=' + merchantId);
* if('<testcaseName>' == 'search by email') karate.set('pathVar','/search?email=' + email);

Given path pathVar
```

Is there any other way to send them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `params` keyword: https://github.com/intuit/karate#params

Any `null` values will NOT be sent. See this example: [`dynamic-params.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature)

So you can do something like this:

```
Given path '/search'
And params { merchantId: '#(a)', email: '#(b)' }
```

So depending on the values of the variables `a` and `b` you can control your test the way you want.